# Two functions in one Kafka stage. Same State Directory Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have an application that consumes objects (Type A) from Kafka streams.
It then normalises the object (Type B), and finally combines the objects using a generated Key (taken from object). The output produces a final object (Type C) which has some data, as well as a list of the objects identified as similar.

My problem is that when starting the application I get the following error

```
Failed to start bean 'streamsBuilderFactoryManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to initialize state, this can happen if multiple instances of Kafka Streams are running in the same state directory
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$$Lambda$914/000000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.voxcarrier.sip.transformation.Application.main(Application.java:16) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to initialize state, this can happen if multiple instances of Kafka Streams are running in the same state directory
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to initialize state, this can happen if multiple instances of Kafka Streams are running in the same state directory
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:333) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:81) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to initialize state, this can happen if multiple instances of Kafka Streams are running in the same state directory
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.initializeProcessId(StateDirectory.java:185) ~[kafka-streams-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:677) ~[kafka-streams-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:581) ~[kafka-streams-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:316) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I have 2 functions

First Function:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<?, TypeA>, KStream<?,TypeB>> normaliseTypeaObject() {
    log.info("Starting Normalize");
    return l ->
        l
            .peek((k,v)-> log.info(v))
            .mapValues(this::normalise);
}
```

Second function:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<?, TypeB>, KStream<String, TypeC>> correlation() {
    log.info("Starting Correlate");
    return keyGenerator()
        .andThen(correlate());
}
```

They are used but the following Stage Function:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<?, TypeA>, KStream<String, TypeC>> correlationStageFunction(){
    log.info("Correlate Stage");
    return normaliseTypeaObject()
        .andThen(correlate.correlation());
}
```

Every time I start the application I receive the error, even if I cleared the state directory.

I'm at a loss, as the only things I find are related to 2 separate applications using the same state directory. I feel that this is the same, but as I call them under 1 function as far as the Kafka configuration is compared, it not as simple as separating them in the config.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi Conor. To mark your question as solved, do not edit it and add "solved" to the title. Instead, check the checkmark next to an answer (once the timer has elapsed when self-answering).

Comment: no problem, thanks for the tip. I had tried, and din't want people wasting their time looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

It was a stupid one that I didn't notice.

**@Bean** obviously caused the class to be loaded twice throwing the error.